# Script to email inactive sheets of a sheet workbook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script to send the active sheet of a workbook sheet in excel to a mailing list

```
function SendaMailOK(){

var DateName1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet( ).getRange("B4").getValue();
var newdate = new Date(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet( ).getRange("B4").getValue());
var d = Utilities.formatDate(newdate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yyyy");
var f = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Adresses Mail');

//Send active sheet as email attachment

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var ssID = ss.getId();
var sheetgId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
var sheetName = ss.getSheetName();

var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export?" + "format=xlsx" +  "&gid="+sheetgId+ "&portrait=false" + "&exportFormat=xlsx";

var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
}
});

var contents = result.getContent();

var subject = "Rapport du " + d;
var body = "Bonjour, \n\nCi-joint le rapport, \n \nCdlt";

var n=f.getLastRow();
for (var i = 1; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
var emailAddress = f.getRange(i,1).getValue();
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xlsx"}]});
}
};
```

After modifying my file, I need to send 2 sheets of the workbook as attachments and no longer the active sheet.

Problem, I can't adapt the script.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Instead of `getActiveSheet()` use `getSheetByName(put_here_the_sheet_name)`. If you need further help, please start by cleaning up and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

#### Sending multiple files

I played around with your code a little and found a way to do it taking from some of the work that Tanaike has done in this area.  If you don't know where to look for stuff like this then always check out Tanaikes work because I've always found it to be well done.

```
function SendaMailOK() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let esh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  let ssID = ss.getId();
  let token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  let emails = esh.getRange(1, 1, esh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().join(',');
  const names = ['Sheet0', 'Sheet1'];
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~names.indexOf(sh.getName()));
  let files = [];
  shts.forEach((sh, i) => {
    let d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sh.getRange("B4").getValue()), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yyyy");
    let sheetgId = sh.getSheetId();
    let url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssID + "/export?" + "format=xlsx" + "&gid=" + sheetgId + "&portrait=false" + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
    let contents = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token } }).getBlob().setName(`${sh.getName()}.xlsx`);
    files.push(contents);
  });
  var subject = `Files: ${names.join(', ')}`;
  var body = "Hello, here are your files";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emails, subject, body, { attachments: files });
}
```

Comment: Great!  That works.....Thanks